# No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'Number'

Tags: angular, typescript, indexing, ngfor

I have 2 *ngFor with 2 index for each them.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let groupItems of item.itemsList | groupBy: 'category'; index as i">
    <div class="field-view">
        <div class="label-view">
            {{ groupItems.groupName }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of groupItems.items; index as j">
        <div class="field-view" [itemValue]="item.total">
                  <div class="value-view">
                    {{ item.total }}
                  </div>
               </div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

I want to put on total `i` and `j`  index
I tried to use `[itemValue]="item.total[i][j]"` and  `{{ item.total[i][j] }}`
but show error   `No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'Number'.`

Can you share with me any idea please?

I have this Josn:

```
[
    {
      "id":3,
        "itemsList": [
            {
                "total": 20000,
                "itemId": "123",
                "category": "test"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "itemsList": [
            {
                "total": 2000,
                "itemId": "235",
                "category": "test1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "itemsList": [
            {
                "total": 200,
                "itemId": "5452",
                "category": "test"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: can you share the value of item.itemsList?

Comment: Yes I share it. Thank you

Comment: Do you have a type definition for the object item.itemList or itemValue? Could you share it?

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided, this looks like a typing mismatch problem.
Remember that the type Number is not the same as number:

- **Number** is an Object wrapped around number.
- **number** is a primitive data type

Here is some [documentation](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/typescript/typescript-number/#number-vs-number) you can check.

Make sure you are not mixing the two in your type definitions. You can assign **number** to **Number** but it won't work the other way around.